# "Choose File" button not working as a button in mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mobile-website

I have created an online web app that is responsive to different browsers(desktop, tablet, mobile) using Bootstrap framework. After which, I converted the web app to a mobile web app and published on Google Play store and downloaded this android app on my phone.

However, I came to realised that the "Choose File" in the form is not working on app in the phone and can't be clicked. It is working fine when accessed on the url with a desktop browser.

Can someone explain what is the problem and what is a solution to this?

Comment: Hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371281/1318946) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Omar,

Unfortunately, I had this same issue with a Web App I built about 2 months ago. This is apparently a problem with Android Kit-Kat and above. Google does not plan to fix this either as far as I know, as the issue has been opened with them for almost a year now.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220

Your best bet for now is to either build a native Android app, or simply just not support Android until a fix is released from Google

Comment: Sorry, just to be move specific, this issue only pretains to the Andorid Webkit/Webview

Comment: Thanks for your advice but seriously is there no other solution?

Comment: user2192094, Sorry I thought Omar was the original OP, but no I searched stackoverflow & others for almost two months with no luck. The worst part was, if you visited your site from the chrome and/or broswer app in android, it worked! It is a problem strictly with the WebView/WebKit when building an Android app. It is supposed to be fixed with the next major version of Android, but who knows when that will be. You can try searching stackoverflow and implementing some of the proposed solution but at least in my situation, not one of them worked

Comment: thanks for your explanation! I will find another way.