# Android - Choose File button in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm having a problem where I've got a page loaded in WebView - I'm not going to post code for the entire application, because my problem is very specific: the "Choose File" button in my HTML page works on the Android Studio created emulator, but nowhere else.

The button runs this code:

```
<input type='file' id='fileInput' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event);'>
var openFile = function(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            /* various string parsing */
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

This works perfectly fine on my emulator which is API 23: clicking the button opens the device's default File chooser to pick a file. However, on my actual phone, which is API 16, clicking this button does nothing. Furthermore, on a Genymotion emulator, which is API 18, clicking the button does nothing. Is there something I can do to fix this? The button produces no error messages on both my phone and the Genymotion emulator, it just sits there and nothing happens.

I need the app to work on a device that allows speech-to-text, so I can't only use the emulator, as much as I'd like to.

Comment: Hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371281/1318946) will help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set `WebChromeClient` for Choose File

**CODE**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;

public class BrowserScreen extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String url = "url";       

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser_activity);
        initFields();
        setListeners();        
    }               

    public void initFields() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    }    

    public void setListeners() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");

                view.clearHistory();
            }        
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            }

            //The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }    
        });

            webView.loadUrl(url);    

        final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
                = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (webView.canGoBack() == true) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"Button3\").innerHTML = \"bye\";");
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void openAndroidDialog() {
            AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                    = new AlertDialog.Builder(BrowserScreen.this);
            myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
            myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
            myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
            myDialog.show();
        }   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a WebChromeClient class already, but I didn't know about the openFileChooser methods.

Comment: @KanaiyaKatarmal can u pls help me

Comment: i m failed to upload image

Comment: Where does `MyTaskBrowserScreen.this` come from?

Comment: replace MyTaskBrowserScreen to BrowserScreen

Answer (score 12):

The Accepted Answers is not working for me. I found new answer from [Google Chromium Samples.](https://github.com/googlearchive/chromium-webview-samples/blob/master/input-file-example/app/src/main/java/inputfilesample/android/chrome/google/com/inputfilesample/MainFragment.java)

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityWebviewBinding binding;

    public static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_webview);

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.button_register_now));
        }

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        WebSettings webSettings = binding.webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        binding.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                return handleUri(uri);
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
                return handleUri(uri);
            }

            private boolean handleUri(final Uri uri) {

                if (uri != null) {

                    Log.i("TAG", "Uri =" + uri);

                    // Based on some condition you need to determine if you are going to load the url
                    // in your web view itself or in a browser.
                    // You can use `host` or `scheme` or any part of the `uri` to decide.
                    if (uri.getLastPathSegment() != null) {
                        if (uri.getLastPathSegment().contains("p1_business_part1.php")) {
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        binding.webView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "Error:" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.loadUrl("about:blank");
            }
        });
        binding.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e("TAG", "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                return true;
            }
        });

        binding.webView.loadUrl("your_url");
    }

    /**
     * More info this method can be found at
     * http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
     *
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (binding.webView.canGoBack()) {
            binding.webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Hope it will helps others.

Thank you.

Comment: This code is not showing any Dialog box to select camera or image file selection option ?

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Activity Full Source:**

```
package your.package.name;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class FileChooser extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> fileChooserCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri home = Uri.parse("https://fengyuanchen.github.io/photo-editor/");

        WebView view = new WebView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView vw, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (request.getUrl().toString().contains(home.getHost())) {
                    vw.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
                    vw.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView vw, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                                             FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (fileChooserCallback != null) {
                    fileChooserCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                fileChooserCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent selectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                selectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                selectionIntent.setType("*/*");

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, selectionIntent);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 0);

                return true;
            }
        });
        view.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) ->
        {
            WebView vw = (WebView) v;
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && vw.canGoBack()) {
                vw.goBack();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        });
        view.setDownloadListener((uri, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength) -> handleURI(uri));
        view.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            handleURI(((WebView) v).getHitTestResult().getExtra());

            return true;
        });

        view.loadUrl(home.toString());

        setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        fileChooserCallback.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{Uri.parse(intent.getDataString())});
        fileChooserCallback = null;
    }

    private void handleURI(String uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(uri.replaceFirst("^blob:", "")));

            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Webview - Single & Multiple files Select

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1'
```

java code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bivoiclient.utils.Constants;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.controller.DialogSelectionListener;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.model.DialogConfigs;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.model.DialogProperties;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.view.FilePickerDialog;

import java.io.File;

public class WebBrowserScreen extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
    private FilePickerDialog dialog;
    private String LOG_TAG = "DREG";
    private Uri[] results;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complain);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new PQClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.loadUrl(YOUR_WEBVIEW_URL);

    }

    private void openFileSelectionDialog() {

        if (null != dialog && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        //Create a DialogProperties object.
        final DialogProperties properties = new DialogProperties();

        //Instantiate FilePickerDialog with Context and DialogProperties.
        dialog = new FilePickerDialog(WebBrowserScreen.this, properties);
        dialog.setTitle("Select a File");
        dialog.setPositiveBtnName("Select");
        dialog.setNegativeBtnName("Cancel");
        properties.selection_mode = DialogConfigs.MULTI_MODE; // for multiple files
//        properties.selection_mode = DialogConfigs.SINGLE_MODE; // for single file
        properties.selection_type = DialogConfigs.FILE_SELECT;

        //Method handle selected files.
        dialog.setDialogSelectionListener(new DialogSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedFilePaths(String[] files) {
                results = new Uri[files.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    String filePath = new File(files[i]).getAbsolutePath();
                    if (!filePath.startsWith("file://")) {
                        filePath = "file://" + filePath;
                    }
                    results[i] = Uri.parse(filePath);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "file path: " + filePath);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "file uri: " + String.valueOf(results[i]));
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        });
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                    if (null != results && results.length >= 1) {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                    } else {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                }
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        });
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                    if (null != results && results.length >= 1) {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                    } else {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                }
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

    public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            openFileSelectionDialog();

            return true;
        }

    }

    //Add this method to show Dialog when the required permission has been granted to the app.
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FilePickerDialog.EXTERNAL_READ_PERMISSION_GRANT: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (dialog != null) {
                        openFileSelectionDialog();
                    }
                } else {
                    //Permission has not been granted. Notify the user.
                    Toast.makeText(WebBrowserScreen.this, "Permission is Required for getting list of files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public class PQClient extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressBar progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
            if (url.contains("mailto:")) {

                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                // Here we can open new activity

                return true;

            } else {
                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Show loader on url load
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
                    "document.getElementById('android-app').style.display='none';})()");

            try {
                // Close progressDialog
                progressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```