# Why not working choose file option in webview?

Tags: android, webview, upload

Why not working choose file option in webview?I have a wordpress website ,i used **contactform7** plugin for upload-file option.but when , click on **choose-file** button in webview , this is not working.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://grocerydoorstep.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    }

    public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer may helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Comment: Hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371281/1318946) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**,maybe this link will be useful to you. Kindly check it out [file chooser inside Webview](https://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128) 
In the above link they explained about how to pick a file and how to capture a file using camera and get its path from Webview .