# choose files dont work on the phone using webview

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a `button` choose files in website, when you press the button on your computer it works and when you press the button on the phone does not work what solution, the site shows using `WebView`

```
        mywebsite = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywebsite);
        pd_loading = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pd_loading);
        mywebsite.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mywebsite.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        mywebsite.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebsite.loadUrl(Information.URL_Home);
        mywebsite.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view ,String url)
            {
                pd_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mywebsite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                Toasty.error(Home.this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
            }

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), 101);
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            }

            // For Android > 4.1 - undocumented method
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");

            }

            // For Android > 5.0
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                startActivityForResult(fileChooserParams.createIntent(), 101);
                return true;
            }

        });
```

onActivittyResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                            : intent.getData();
                    if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                    } else if (afterLolipop != null) {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            afterLolipop.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                            afterLolipop = null;
                        }
                    }
                    mUploadMessage = null;
                }
        }

    }
```

these codes don't work I just want to choose a picture of a computer I hope help me thanks

Comment: where is the JS code for calling `openFileChooser` method on button click ?

Answer (score 0):

When I faced a similar kind of issue, I have made use of `setWebChromeClient()` method found from [this souce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34891790/6503228).

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;

public class BrowserScreen extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String url = "url";


    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser_activity);
        initFields();
        setListeners();


    }




    public void initFields() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    }


    public void setListeners() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");

                view.clearHistory();
            }


        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {


            }

            //The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }


        });



            webView.loadUrl(url);


        final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
                = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (webView.canGoBack() == true) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"Button3\").innerHTML = \"bye\";");
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void openAndroidDialog() {
            AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                    = new AlertDialog.Builder(BrowserScreen.this);
            myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
            myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
            myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
            myDialog.show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working , when click to choose files button not opened gallery please help me