# Will new Android version be compatable with old WebView file Picker methods

Tags: java

I have Noticed that there are different ways to handle the file picking in web views. It seems to depend on the Android version that the app is running on.

As an example. I saw this code in many stack overflow answer.

```
//The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }
```

Is it possible that olf ways to handle the File picker in the web view will no longer work in an upcoming version of android?

For context. These are the questions i have been looking at.
[Android - Choose File button in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891352/android-choose-file-button-in-webview)
[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

Comment: When using undocumented features you are completely on your own ...

Comment: @Henry what do you mean with undocumented features? Is the file picking feature an undocumented feature?

Comment: I was referring to the first line of your posted code.