# webview, Android File Chooser not calling froms Android

Tags: android

I have a problem with the upload file button to the Google Form, when the user clicks on the button nothing will happen. what should I do or what should I add, please help?

```
package com.ining.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class KirimTugasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kirim_tugas);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        // Tiga baris di bawah ini agar laman yang dimuat dapat
        // melakukan zoom.
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        // Baris di bawah untuk menambahkan scrollbar di dalam WebView-nya
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdwUcVor4FflN2dDbw15gIAPd4djUR6YiUzEd_bvUN_6oZ1mA/viewform?usp=sf_link");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

set WebChromeClient for Choose File.
check this [Android - Choose File button in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891352/android-choose-file-button-in-webview)

or check google sample
https://github.com/googlearchive/chromium-webview-samples/blob/b18afa96ab6215eed526c19156bf0fe6f5386ad1/input-file-example/app/src/main/java/inputfilesample/android/chrome/google/com/inputfilesample/MainFragment.java